# Is combining multiple SqlCommand into 1 possible?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have multiple queries built in vb.net:

```
'--1st transaction
Using cmd As New SqlCommand(saveloaninfo, gSQlConn)
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using

'--2nd transaction
Using cmd As New SqlCommand(saveloanaccounting, gSQlConn)
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using

'--4th transaction
Using cmd As New SqlCommand(saveloanschedules, gSQlConn)
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using

'--5th transaction
Using cmd As New SqlCommand(savecollaterals, gSQlConn)
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

each transaction contribute to one another and all of them should be inserted. my problem is, when one of the transaction throws and error and the rest doenst, data will be incomplete. I tried enclosing them inside

```
Using tscope As New TransactionScope()
    
End Using
```

still got the same problem.
Any other suggestion. thanks.

Comment: Did you `Open()` the `gSQlConn` from inside of the `Using tscope`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`SqlTransaction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction) class on [`SqlCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.-ctor) (third parameter) to solve this:

```
Dim gSQLTrans As SqlTransaction

'start a transaction
gSQLTrans = gSQlConn.BeginTransaction("NameOfTransaction")

Try
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand(saveloaninfo, gSQlConn, gSQLTrans)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using

    '--2nd transaction
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand(saveloanaccounting, gSQlConn, gSQLTrans)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using

    '--4th transaction
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand(saveloanschedules, gSQlConn, gSQLTrans)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using

    '--5th transaction
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand(savecollaterals, gSQlConn, gSQLTrans)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using

    'commit to save the changes on the database.
    gSQLTrans.Commit()
Catch ex As Exception
    'rollback to revert the changes of the transaction.
    gSQLTrans.Rollback()
End Try
```